# What does this notation mean? $\mathbb{P}_{x\sim \mathcal{D}}$: Clarification in the definition of generalization error $R(h)$

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, notation

I was reading the book foundations of machine learning by Mehryar Mohri, Afshin Rostamizadeh and Ameet Talwalkar, and I came up with this definition of *generalization error*:
[image]

I dont understand what this means. I would like a more formal explanation of what they mean by the notation

$$
\mathbb{P}_{x\sim \mathcal{D}} [h(x)\neq c(x)].
$$

Maybe I'm wrong but does this mean that given a random variable $X$ taking values in the domain of $c$ with distribution $\mathcal{D}$ the generalization error is

$$
R(h) = \mathbb{P}[h(X)\neq c(X)]
$$

Again, I just want a formal definition of what they are referring to. I understand the intuitive idea of the definition, they want to measure the probability of model $h$ being wrong when classifying.

Comment: Cross posted at [Maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4645892/1074816).

Comment: Your English description is fine.  It's unclear what you are looking for in a "formal definition."  Would that be a statement of the probability axioms?  Of what a distribution is?  Of what a random variable is?

Comment: @whuber Maybe I was just referring to what it means in slightly clearer terms. Because I had seen an explanation in another question but in mathematical terms I didn't know how to formulate it well. But if my interpretation is right then it is clearer to me. Thank you.

Comment: This is merely a (fairly clear and explicit) way of expressing the chance of the event $h(x)\ne c(x),$ namely of making an error.  The content of the quotation consists of expressing this chance as an expectation.